# Intuition behind popping the values only when the set is empty

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-traversal

I am solving a question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/reconstruct-itinerary/description/.  The question is:

```
Given a list of airline tickets represented by pairs of departure and 
arrival airports [from, to], reconstruct the itinerary in order. All of 
the tickets belong to a man who departs from JFK. Thus, the itinerary 
must begin with JFK.
```

For e.g., if `tickets = [["MUC", "LHR"], ["JFK", "MUC"], ["SFO", "SJC"], ["LHR", "SFO"]]`, the the output should be: `["JFK", "MUC", "LHR", "SFO", "SJC"]`.

I wrote the following code, which (understandably) breaks on the input `[["JFK","KUL"],["JFK","NRT"],["NRT","JFK"]]`, because as per my code, the node "NRT" remains unvisited:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> findItinerary(vector<pair<string, string>> tickets) {
        if(tickets.empty()) return vector<string>();

        vector<string> result;
        unordered_map<string, multiset<string>> itinerary;

        for(auto& each : tickets)
            itinerary[each.first].insert(each.second);

        stack<string> myStack;
        myStack.push("JFK");
        while(!myStack.empty()) {
            string topVal=myStack.top();
            result.push_back(topVal);
            myStack.pop();
            if(!itinerary[topVal].empty()) {
                myStack.push(*itinerary[topVal].begin());
                itinerary[topVal].erase(itinerary[topVal].begin());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

To overcome this, one of the upvoted solutions proposes this small change:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> findItinerary(vector<pair<string, string>> tickets) {
        if(tickets.empty()) return vector<string>();

        vector<string> result;
        unordered_map<string, multiset<string>> itinerary;

        for(auto& each : tickets)
            itinerary[each.first].insert(each.second);

        stack<string> myStack;
        myStack.push("JFK");
        while(!myStack.empty()) {
            string topVal=myStack.top();
            if(itinerary[topVal].empty()) {   //--->this if condition
                result.push_back(topVal);
                myStack.pop();
            }
            else {
                myStack.push(*itinerary[topVal].begin());
                itinerary[topVal].erase(itinerary[topVal].begin());
            }
        }

        reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
        return result;
    }
};
```

Now, I worked on this code with the example `[["JFK","KUL"],["JFK","NRT"],["NRT","JFK"]]`, and saw how it inserts the values into the `result` vector in a reverse manner; but I fail to understand the **intuition** behind that if condition:

**How does popping from the stack only when the set is empty, ensure that this test case is taken care of?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is essentially to find an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in a directed graph where every [from, to] pair represents an edge.

The upvoted answer uses an algorithm called [Hierholzer's algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hierholzers-algorithm-directed-graph/) (Hierholzer's algorithm is originally used to find Eulerian **cycle**, but it's easy to revise it for Eulerian **path**). Generally, it

> keep following unused edges and removing them until we get stuck. **Once we get stuck, we back-track to the nearest vertex in our current path that has unused edges, and we repeat the process until all the edges have been used.**

The emphasized part is the difference between your solution and the upvoted solution.

P.S. Though the algorithm is simple, the proof of correctness is not that trivial. If you are interested in it, you can search it on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

After visiting a `to` city it is removed which effectively means that `to` city as a intermediate `from` city has been visited and no need to be considered the next time the corresponding `from` city is visited otherwise it will be a never ending loop with no stopping condition.

Thus the `if` statement is where the checking happens whether all the `to` cities for a `from` city have visited already. It pretty much acts like a visited array keeping track of all the cities visited so far.